# ¿Cómo hago para que se muestren los comentarios de mi página web en EJS?

Tags: nodejs, ejs

Estoy teniendo un pequeño problema con una página web que estoy haciendo con NodeJS y el motor de vistas EJS, más en concreto con el sistema de comentarios. Cuando se envía un comentario, el servidor en NodeJS envía un array con todos los comentarios publicados a la página donde se tienen que mostrar; el cual almacena objetos que contienen dos propiedades: 'autor', cuyo valor es el autor del comentario, y 'contenido', que es el comentario en sí mismo. El problema es que a la hora de enviarlos los comentarios directamente no se muestran.
He comprobado si esos dos datos se estaban recibiendo y, dado que así era, posteriormente he comprobado si el objeto que los contiene se estaba almacenando en el array; cosa que también era así. De todo esto deduje que el problema estaba en el siguiente código:

```
<% for (var i = 0; i < comentarios.length; i ++) { %>
            <% var autor = comentarios.autor; %>
            <% var comentario = comentarios.comentario; %>
            <div class = "row">
                <div class = "container">
                    <div class = "card-mt4">
                        <div class = "card-body">
                            <p><i class = "far fa-comments"></i> <%= titulo_comentario %></p>
                            <p><% comentario %></p>
                            <p>Publicado por: <small><% autor %></small></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <% } %>
```

Este ciclo for es el que se encarga de mostrar los comentarios, pero no veo dónde puede estar el fallo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea mostrar los elementos de un tipo [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array) en una plantilla de [`ejs`](https://ejs.co/). Sin embargo al usar `comentarios.autor` y `comentarios.comentario` no se muestran en la plantilla.

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución está en entender el tipo de dato que estamos intentando mostrar en nuestra plantilla.

Actualmente tienes:

```
comentarios.autor
comentarios.comentario
```

Lo cual producirá `undefined` en ambos casos, ya que `comentarios` es un `Array`, y por lo tanto no posee los atributos o propiedades llamadas `autor` o `comentario`. Por ejemplo:

```js
let comentarios = [
  {autor: 'Mauricio', comentario: 'Este es un comentario'},
  {autor: 'SCC38', comentario: 'Este es otro comentario'}
];
for(let i = 0; i < comentarios.length; i++) {
  console.log(`autor: ${comentarios.autor}`);
  console.log(`comentario: ${comentarios.comentario}`);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

**Usando el índice iterado.**

Lo que debes hacer es indicar el índice del elemento que estás iterando en tu `Array` de comentarios, por ejemplo:

```js
let comentarios = [
  {autor: 'Mauricio', comentario: 'Este es un comentario'},
  {autor: 'SCC38', comentario: 'Este es otro comentario'}
];
for(let i = 0; i < comentarios.length; i++) {
  console.log(`autor: ${comentarios[i].autor}`); // uso el índice i
  console.log(`comentario: ${comentarios[i].comentario}`); // uso el índice i
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

**Usando `for ... of`**

Otra forma un poco más intuitiva es usar el bucle [`for ... of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for...of), de esta forma la cosa se ve mejor y no nos enredamos con los índices:

```js
let comentarios = [
  {autor: 'Mauricio', comentario: 'Este es un comentario'},
  {autor: 'SCC38', comentario: 'Este es otro comentario'}
];
for(let comentario of comentarios) {
  console.log(`autor: ${comentario.autor}`); // uso comentario (singular)
  console.log(`comentario: ${comentario.comentario}`); // uso comentario (singular)
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

**Edición**

Cuando trabajamos con los valores de las variables que vamos a mostrar al cliente, usando `ejs`, las mismas las debemos encerrar en el siguiente formato:

```
<%= nombre_variable %>
```

En tu plantilla hace falta esto para que termine de funcionar.

Por último tu plantilla puede quedar parecida a la siguiente:

```html
<!-- uso 'coment' para evitar un uso repetido de la variable 'comentario' -->
<% for (let coment of comentarios) {%>  
  <% let autor = coment.autor; %>
  <% let comentario = coment.comentario; %>
  <div class = "row">
    <div class = "container">
      <div class = "card-mt4">
        <div class = "card-body">
          <p><i class = "far fa-comments"></i> <%= titulo_comentario %></p>
          <p><%= comentario %></p>
          <p>Publicado por: <small><%= autor %></small></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% } %>
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Lo pondré en práctica ahora mismo y luego ya comentaré cómo me fue. Muchas gracias por contestar.

Comment: Lo he intentado con el bucle "for ... of", pero sigue sin mostrarlos.

Comment: @SCC38 si, disculpa, me concentré en el error principal pero olvidé corregir el error en la plantilla. Tienes actualmente `<% autor %>`, pero lo correcto es `<%= autor %>`. Lo mismo para la variable `comentario`. Acabo de editar la respuesta con el código de la plantilla corregido. Saludos

Comment: Lo corregiré en mi código y luego comentaré si se solucionó o no el problema, que espero que sí.

Comment: Solucionado. Muchas gracias.